# Generalization of the identity $x^n - y^n = (x-y)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i y^{n-1-i}$ to non-integer exponents?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory

I recently came across a problem in which an expression of the form

\begin{align*}
x^d - y^d, \quad d \notin \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

appeared. If we had $d \in \mathbb{N}$, we could of course rewrite the expression using the familiar formula mentioned in the title and say

\begin{align*}
x^d - y^d = (x-y)\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} x^i y^{d-1-i},
\end{align*}
but given that $d$ is not an integer, this doesn't even make sense. 
Does anybody know of a formula that relates $x^d - y^d$ ($d \notin \mathbb{N}$) to some expression in which $x-y$ appears? In other words, I am looking for a function $f(x,y)$ such that for a fixed $d \notin \mathbb{N}$

\begin{align*}
x^d - y^d = (x-y)\cdot f(x,y)
\end{align*}

holds identically. A naive guess would be $f(x,y):= \int_{0}^{d-1} x^t y^{d-1-t} \hspace{0.1cm} dt$, but this evaluates to

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{d-1}-y^{d-1}}{\ln(x) - \ln(y)}
\end{align*}
and gives the formula

\begin{align*}
x^d - y^d = (\ln(x) - \ln(y))\cdot \int_0^d x^t y^{d-t} \hspace{0.1cm} dt,
\end{align*}
in which $x-y$ *doesn't* appear. Any ideas?

Comment: The upper limit of sigma (d-1) is not integer i think  it must be integer.

Comment: Isn't in wikipedia in the pages "list of series" also the binomial-series (even with fractional power) listed? I vaguely recall to have seen this there.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms You were right. It seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
x^d&=(1+(x-1))^d=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{d}k(x-1)^k\\
y^d&=(1+(y-1))^d=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{d}k(y-1)^k\\
\hline
x^d-y^d&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{d}k\big[(x-1)^k-(y-1)^k\big]\\
&=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{d}k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-1)^i(y-1)^{k-1-i}
\end{align}

Comment: Pretty cool! Don't think I ever heard of or saw the generalized binomial theorem before @GottfriedHelms mentioned it and you used it.